# AJAX POSTing to PHP isn't working

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I am trying to POST a JSON to PHP where it should be decoded and pushed to MySQL database.

This is my JavaScript code.

```
    var dictstring = "{sensorid: \""+ name +"\", x: " +pos.x +" ,y: "+pos.y+"}";
                    console.log(dictstring);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                         dataType: "json",
                        url: "myfile.php",
                        data: JSON.stringify(dictstring),
                        success: function(data){
                        alert('Success');
                        },
                    error: function(e){

                    console.log(e.message);
                        }
                    });
```

And this is my PHP code

```
<?php


$jsonData = file_get_contents('php://input');

$data_back = json_decode($jsonData);
$unit = $data_back->{"sensorid"};
$x_axis = $data_back->{"x"};
$y_axis = $data_back->{"y"};


// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("xxxxxxx:xxxx","xxxxx","xxxx","xxxxxxxx");

// Check
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//Insert Values
$sql_hm = "INSERT INTO xxxx(unit, x_axis, y_axis)
VALUES ('$unit', $x_axis, $y_axis)";

if ($con->query($sql_hm) === TRUE) {
    echo "values inserted successfully"; 

} else {
     echo "No data ";
}



?>
```

I know the PHP part works -  I tried POSTing JSON data with contentType: application/json from a REST client app and it works. But when I am trying it with my Javascript code, it isnt POSTing. I can see the "dictstring" string value in console. I cannot see the "Success" alert too. Interestingly, "Success" alert is shown if I remove the dataType: "json" line. But, POSTing is still not happening as I cannot see the values in database.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why is `dictstring` a string? And why are you passing it to `JSON.stringify()`?

Comment: I think you don't need to `stringify` as `dictstring` is already a JSON String.

Comment: Don't write your own JSON, and don't post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dictstring = "{sensorid: \""+ name +"\", x: " +pos.x +" ,y: "+pos.y+"}";
```

You have a string.

```
data: JSON.stringify(dictstring),
```

Which you then convert to a JSON representation of that string.

```
$data_back = json_decode($jsonData);
```

Which you decode to a string.

```
$unit = $data_back->{"sensorid"};
```

Which you try to treat like an object.

---

Start with an object, not a string:

```
var dictstring = { sensorid: name, x: pos.x, y: pos.y };
```

… you probably want a different variable name too.

Answer (score 0):

`dictstring` is already in JSON format, you don't need `JSON.stringify` in your JS

Comment: tried removing JSON.stringify(dictstring) and kept it as data: dictstring - but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

`dataType: "json"` is to be used if the data returned from server is `JSON`

You can create an array of messages and then use `echo json_encode($array);` to return `JSON` data to your js.

Coming to your problem, from the question and the information you've supplied, I couldn't find an obvious problem, but I could suggest to use `console.log(data)` in your success function and see what is returned. You'll at least know if it hit your php page or returned with some error like `404` or `500.`

Try `$data_back['sensorid']`

or

Just `print_r($data_back);` and see the data structure of `$data_back` and then try access the data accordingly.

Comment: tried that. It isn't receving the json data. shows error </span> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\heatmap\myfile.php on line <i>7

Answer (score -1):

Okay it might sound silly but have you made sure to state that you're using JQuery in the java script because the amount of times I've been doing ajax and i cant figure out why it wont work and its because I haven't declared the JQuery.

like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
```